# Sending Complete Chain from Common Access Card (CAC)?

Tags: security, jaas, webservice-client, pkcs#11, cac

I'm attempting to enable SSL communication from a web service client (Axis2) using the certificate on the user's CAC card.  Works like a charm....UNTIL the web server is CAC enabled.  At that point the SSL connection is rejected with the error message that the other certificates in the chain were not included.

I have ensured that the provider is available, either by adding it to the security.properties file or creating it programatically.

My current approach is to simply set the system properties:
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "NONE");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS11");

I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752890/how-to-connect-to-https-server-using-common-access-card/753129#753129) question/answer that this approach only sends the "end entity" certificate.  Apparently I need to implement my own X509KeyManager.  This is new ground for me, can anyone suggest a good reference or provide samples of how to do so?

Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: are you sure you want to be talking about CAC cards here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best key manager implementation depends on the issuer of the certificates you expect to be using.

If the certificate on the user's CAC will *always* be issued by a specific CA, simply store that issuer's certificate and any intermediate certificates further up the chain in a PKCS #7 file. In the [`getCertificateChain()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager.html#getCertificateChain(java.lang.String)) method, this collection can be appended blindly to the user's certificate and returned.

If things aren't quite that simple, but a complete list of possible issuers can be enumerated, obtain all of their certificates, and *their* issuer's certificates, and so on, up to the root certificates.

Add all of the root certificates to a key store as trusted entries. Bundle the intermediate certificates in a PKCS-#7–format file.

Implement [`X509KeyManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager.html) (or extend [`X509ExtendedKeyManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedKeyManager.html) if you're working with `SSLEngine`). Specifically, in the `getCertificateChain()` method, you'll use a [`CertPathBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertPathBuilder.html) to create a valid chain from the user's certificate to a trusted root. The [target](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509CertSelector.html#setCertificate(java.security.cert.X509Certificate)) is the certificate that you load from the user's CAC with the `alias` parameter. The [trusted roots](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/PKIXBuilderParameters.html#PKIXBuilderParameters(java.security.KeyStore,%20java.security.cert.CertSelector)) are the certificates in trust store that you created; the intermediate certificates can be [loaded](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificates(java.io.InputStream)) from the PKCS #7 file and [added to the builder parameters.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/PKIXParameters.html#addCertStore(java.security.cert.CertStore)) Once the chain is built, [get the certificate path](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertPathBuilderResult.html#getCertPath()) and [convert it](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertPath.html#getCertificates()) to an array. This is the result of the `getCertificateChain()` method.

If you can't predict who will be issuing the user's certificate, you might be able to obtain the intermediate certificates at runtime from an LDAP directory or other repository. That's a whole new level of difficulty.

Comment: If you know the intermediates and control the server you're connecting to then you can add needed intermediates to the server configuration instead of changing the client.

Comment: Possibly. It depends on the server. When a server is misconfigured with an incomplete chain, it isn't unreasonable for clients to treat it as a bug. Likewise, it is reasonable to have the same expectation for client authentication. In this question, the poster has indicated that they control the client, and has asked for help in implementing a key manager—an approach that satisfies the expectation to provide a complete chain.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm going to try this out with a regular socket and then figure out how to insert the same change into the Axis2 configuration.