# Common Access Card (CAC) Authentication using Vaadin Application

Tags: java, authentication, cac

I am creating a Vaadin web application that requires users to authenticate via login and password, I would like to know if it is possible to add CAC authentication as another mean of authentication.

**In summary, my goal is to allow access to the website if the user is already authenticated with its CAC or require standard login (name/password) if the user is not CAC authenticated**

By searching and googling around I have found [Java PKCS#11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/p11guide.html#Login), but it looks like it is a library for desktop integration.

Also I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544056/common-access-card-cac-authentication-using-java?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752890/how-to-connect-to-https-server-using-common-access-card/753129#753129) posts, that look similar to my situation but actually they are not. The first one talks about requirement of certification for the whole web application by configuring a web server. The second one presents Java PKCS#11 as desktop solution.

Again, what I wish to have is a "parallel" login, if the browser sends a CAC certificate to the server, the server should not require standard login, otherwise yes. Is it possible? Also, if the CAC certificate is sent to the server is there a way to retrieve data about this CAC, like owner's name?

Comment: This is not vaadin specific, it's just plain servlet container. You will need to check if the browser did send a client certificate with it and if that one is valid

Comment: Ok, I just need to know how to perform this process of checking if the browser sent a client certificate from the servlet. I will remove the Vaadin tag then.

Comment: What servlet container do you use?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Jetty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a correctly configured servlet container you can use this to read the client certificate (if any exists)

```
String cipherSuite = (String) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite");

if (cipherSuite != null) {
    X509Certificate certChain[] = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    if (certChain != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < certChain.length; i++) {
            System.out.println ("Client Certificate [" + i + "] = "
                    + certChain[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but `cipherSuite` is always null. The CAC card I am using for this test is connected and is listed under my certificates. Should I configure Jetty first?

Comment: Does your jetty request a client certificate at all? If not, then there is no chance the client will send you one

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have not configured SSL on my Jetty. Do you have any information on how to do that?

Comment: Is your jetty the one accepting the https connection, or doe you have a apache/nginx or other server in front of it?

Comment: Jetty is the one which will accept the https connection. I have taken a look at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.6.v20141205/configuring-ssl.html#loading-keys-and-certificates but I could not find out how to configure it to request CAC authentication.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752890/how-to-connect-to-https-server-using-common-access-card and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544056/common-access-card-cac-authentication-using-java these should solve your problem

Comment: Ok, but that question is about implementing a Java client that connects to a HTTPS web application. I need to configure SSL in my web application so the client sends the certificate in the request, and then I can check if this request contains a CAC certificate. If so, the user don't need to use login/password to login in the web app. Does it make sense?

Comment: It is very easy to set up an embedded Jetty server that requests client authentication: One just needs to add the statement SslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true); to the ssl context when configuring the server. Any client that has its certificate in the server's truststore will be able to establish a TLS connection to the server. But the weak point will be to have the correct keys in the truststore...

Comment: Would you have an example on how to add `SslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true);` to the ssl context?