# retrieval of security token upon swipe of CAC card using Java

Tags: java, security, authentication, x509, cac

I am using SCR3310 card reader in Ubuntu, and I have installed the necessary drivers for the smart card reader and it works fine. I have installed pscs_tools to check whether the card/card reader works fine.

I have downloaded few public DoD certificates (.cac) online which consists of the Root CA Certificate and other intermediate certificates.

I have been reading through X.509 certificates, but not sure how to retrieve the X.509 certificate from the above setup. I would also like to know how to authenticate the person using PKI (in Java) and retrieve the unique identifier/security token from the CAC card using the above setup.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

You should use PKCS11 provider to access the smart card. The guide for SUN is:
[p11 guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/p11guide.html)
Also check out this post  [cac auth java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544056/common-access-card-cac-authentication-using-java)