# Server Side Java: Can it read CAC cards and if so, how?

Tags: java, spring, weblogic11g, smartcard-reader, cac

I'm using Java 5 - 6 , Spring 3.1 and WebLogic 11g.

The place where I work (the government ) now requires people to insert a CAC card to get into their PCs.

I would like to learn how to use Server Side Java to read information off of a Common Access Card (CAC) card, possibly for authentication and digital signatures.

I've found extremely little on Google and I have zero idea where to start.

Is it a matter of reading a certificate the CAC generates, then sends through the browser?

If so, I have zero idea with how to start that with that as well.  Can anyone point me to a tutorial  and some code samples?

Comment: Related: [Common Access Card (CAC) Authentication Using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/544056/1065197)

Comment: So it isn't a matter of reading the CAC direclty, but reading a certificate it generates that is sent through the browser?

Comment: Read my answer to a similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16617019/2034089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to learn how to use Server Side Java to read information
>   off of a Common Access Card

The clients will put the CAC card in the *local* machine so the server side does not actually have any access to the CAC card. What you should do in your server side is e.g. do client-side certificate authentication using certificate from CAC card. There are information on how to access a CAC from java

Comment: Cratylus, like I wrote I am starting this from scratch as far as knowing what to do.  Your comment is very useful in that I know which direction to look in.  Could you recommend some tutorials, code samples or some further names to search on for client side certificate authentication?  That is a totally new area for me too.