# CAC authentication in a Java WebApp

Tags: java, authentication, weblogic11g, cac

I saw that there were a few other Java and CAC posts on stackoverflow.   I am a beginner with all of this stuff and I am still trying to a framework of what to do and where to go in my mind.

I am doing work for a big org that is using CACs with Windows 7 boxes to authenticate users who want to get into their PCs.  They stick the CAC in their keyboard and type in a PIN.

My boss would like to alter our Java Webap such that it will not make the users authenticate if they have their CAC in their computer.  If not, they will go through the traditional LDAP login.

We are using WebLogic 11g and Java 6.

From Googling around it seems like there are two approaches:

1. Implement an applet to read the user's CAC and send an SSL certificate to the webapp.
2. Implement "mutually SSL authentication" in the web server, which will cause the browser to send the SSL certificate on the CAC to the webapp

Do I have a correct appraisal of my options?

Which solution is easier?

Which will be less hassle, more robust in the long run?

I know next to nothing about SSL, which seems to be common in both solutions.  I've found a few SSL tutorials that go on at length about abstract concepts.   Can anyone recommend a good tutorial for what I want to do?

Thanks much in advance for any information or tips

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Implement an applet to read the user's CAC and send an SSL certificate to the webapp.
> 2. Implement "mutually SSL authentication" in the web server, which will cause the browser to send the SSL certificate on the CAC to the webapp

You will want to do #2.  You don't really want to have to mess with smart card hardware / software.  Let the OS do all that work.

I've done this on IIS, but generically, to implement this, you will need to configure your web server to require client certificates and to trust the DoD CAs.  You may need to configure your web server to advertise to clients which CAs it trusts.  If the Win7 clients have a client cert that is signed by a CA you trust, the client will attempt to use it.  If it's a smartcard certificate, Windows will automatically prompt the user for the pin; you don't have to worry about that. If the user types the correct pin, the cert will be sent to your web server which should then be able to validate the certificate with the CA.  If it's a valid certificate, your software can then parse the fields in the certificate and use the values to help authenticate the user (ie whether, despite having a valid certificate, the user is actually allowed to login based on their name / email address/ etc).  It's up to you how to handle it from there.

**You will have a much easier time figuring this out and finding information if you forget that the users are using a smartcard or a CAC, and just start with the idea that you're going to use client certificates for authentication**.  Start by creating a self-signed CA test cert.  Then create a server cert for your webserver and a client-certificate signed by your test CA. Add the test CA cert as trusted root cert on the client and the server.  Then attempt to write a small test app that uses the client cert to authenticate to your webserver.  Once you have that working, you can add the DoD CA and try to pull the info out of a CaC certificate.

good luck!