# Authenticating AD server user using DOD issued CAC in java

Tags: java, cac

I have to authenticate an user residing in AD server using the DOD issued CAC(without using any username or password) using java. I will have CAC middle ware  ActiveClient installed in the machine which is required to access the content(user certificates) on CAC. On some research i found that Kerberos +  PKINIT should be used. I am not sure about where to start. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common Access Card (CAC) Authentication Using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544056/common-access-card-cac-authentication-using-java)